# Is it okay to burn CDs of Ubuntu and then sell them for a low or cheap price?

Tags: live-cd, livedvd

Before possibly judging my question, here is my motive. I am a 13 year old teen from the Philippines. I am a Linux Enthusiast (although I still use Windows on my desktop for gaming). I wanted to make some extra money for savings and emergency money. One way I thought of doing that was by burning CD/DVDs of Ubuntu and selling it to people. Maybe for a very cheap price (the price of the CD/DVD itself plus a small profit). I just wanted to know if it would be legal to do this? Yes, i know it is easy to burn your own CD. But I know some people who don't have time to do that. So before planning what to do, I wanted to know if it would be legal and correct to do that? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I am not a lawyer, though I think you cannot sell anything legally without paying a taxes or getting a special permission. Furthermore, it would be a matter of ethics to sell something that is free (and more than free) in a first place.

Nevertheless, you can ask for the compensation of the service of writing the CD (practically selling the service). That would mean: You can offer to sell the CD by the price no less than a CD itself, but even better - for the price that is offered to you. Let the buyer determine the price. Besides that, you should emphasize they could download it online for free. That would be the path to spread the word of Ubuntu and to comprehend the meaning of the word "*ubuntu*" as well. Though I have no doubt for the latter because you already showed a great amount of ethics (not just for 13-year old) by asking this question in a first place.

[image]